# Cartoon where guys from junkyard become transformed cars

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, virtual-worlds

What is the name of this cartoon I've been trying to find for years? It starts in a junkyard with these guys (teens, I think) - they go out and get into these junk cars and turn the ignition switch, then the cartoon starts. They were in a virtual world and they were like transformed cars with wheels as feet. I remember there being a lot of roads, and they drank oil. There was a main villain boss that they were always trying to stop; he was a lot bigger than them and he was some kind of transformed car too. It came on TV back in the late 90s or early 2000s.this a US cartoon in English forgot to mention the cartoon starts with real people in a real junckyard

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you remember any additional details, such as: in which country did you see this cartoon, what language was it in, any detail about the characters? Please check out [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394) and feel free to [edit] more details into your question.

Comment: Is it Megas XLR per chance? I haven’t seen much of it, but I know it has a somewhat similar premise.

Answer (score 2):

The show in question is most likely, as user93743 said, Van Pires.

The show wasn't a cartoon, per se, but large segments of it were done in CGI format, which might qualify.  According to the [Wikipedia Van Pires entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Pires), the show ran during the 1997-1998 season on the Fox channel, which places it in the right time range.

The protagonists were a group of teenagers who had been present in a junkyard the night a meteor came crashing down in the middle of it.  Each one took refuge inside one of the junked cars, and after the crash, discovered that they had been transformed into human/car hybrids, their forms based on the cars they'd been in.

The main villain went by the name 'Tracula', and was, in fact, based on a large truck.  He had minions also based on various kinds of vehicles, and as part of the vampire theme, could create new ones.

Tracula and his minions had the goal of devouring the earth's fuel supplies.  The protagonists used their new forms to stop Tracula's attempts.  However, like Tracula, the heroes had two major weaknesses - a vampiric 'allergy' to sunlight, and a requirement for fuel (gasoline, not oil).  They could turn back to human - I don't recall for certain, but I think getting back into their original car (the one they hid in) was the trigger for that.  Scenes with the human version of the team, or their mentor figure, were live-action.

**Intro**