90s Animation Teens Car Robot VR
Teens jump into car interior or perhaps engine bays. This serves them as a portal into virtual reality. There they themselves turn into robot versions of the cars and fight for some reason or another. I believe the show is American and from the 90s in that it resembles the animation style of ReBoot.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Could it be Van-Pires?

Four ordinary teens were accidentally caught in the path of a falling meteor. The meteor transformed them into heroic robotic guardians to protect the night from the evil forces of Tracula (a reference to "Dracula") and the rest of the Van-Pires. Each Motor-Vater has the ability to fly and they also share the same weaknesses as their enemies; like the Van-Pires, the Motor-Vaters require gas to sustain themselves and must avoid the sun at all costs. To transform, each hero gets into the driver's seat of his or her Carfin (a portmanteau of "car" and "coffin") and shouts, "Mission Ignition!"

Intro



Found with a search for 90s series kids jump into cars and transform into robots to fight

What did I just watch?! Was this genuinely broadcast?

FWIW, this was an unaccepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176467/cartoon-where-guys-from-junkyard-become-transformed-cars/180496#180496

Incredible, yes this it! Thank you. This has bugged me for years.

Might you be thinking of VR Troopers?

The show focused on three teenagers in their late teens, Ryan Steele, Kaitlin Star, and J.B. Reese, living in the fictional West Coast town of Cross World City, California. They regularly attended and were teachers at "Tao's Dojo," a karate studio. Ryan was the most focused martial artist; J.B. was the computer wizard; while Kaitlin was a photographer and budding reporter for the local newspaper, the Underground Voice Daily. One day, Ryan's search for his long-missing father led him and his two friends to a strange laboratory. Inside, a digitized head of Professor Horatio Hart (who is a friend of Ryan's father Tyler) explained the truth about his life's work of having developed extremely advanced virtual reality technology in secret. "VR" is a dimension existing alongside our own; within it lie mutants, aiming at conquering both worlds. The main ruler of these is a creature known as Grimlord, who, unbeknownst to anyone on Earth, has a human identity as billionaire industrialist Karl Ziktor. As Karl Ziktor tries to overcome the barriers of the true reality to allow his armies easy passage from the virtual world, the responsibility of defending the planet on both sides of the dimensional barrier falls on Ryan, Kaitlin and J.B.. They have assistance in the form of armored bodies having incredible firepower. This includes eventual additions to their arsenal, such as a Turbo Cycle, Techno Bazooka, VR Troopertron, VR Shoulder Cannon, VR Battlecruiser/Interceptor and a flying, laser-blasting Skybase.

Intro




No not VR Troopers unfortunately. Thank you.

Hmm... does that prompt any other details that you can edit into your question? Like is the ethnicity wrong? Do they tend to look more like vehicles when they transform? Were the special effects better or worse?
